# How does the command corresponding to [b* main of gdb] during dynamic debugging of IDA?

Tags: debugging, assembly, gdb, breakpoints, ida

my goal is analyze executing specific process's stack.
(i will call that program is P.)
i cannot debug P directly with IDA.
i run python code, then python run P.
i successed that watch P's stack with gdb.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QiGql.png)

1. run remote.py, python code resume at raw_input() function.
   [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/66Cy9.png)
2. check pid, and run "sudo gdb -p PID" in terminal.
3. set breakpoint at appropriate address "b *main+42"
   [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OMTCD.png)
4. gdb continue, and type ENTER to python terminal, gdb meet breakpoint and resume process.
   [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/f1dTw.png)
5. then i can watch stack.
   [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3O3Lo.png)

But gdb is not comfortable, i want this work with IDA.
i do 1 again.
and IDA-Debugger-attach-Local Linux Debugger, attach process.
but i can't set breakpoint at *main+42 address. i can't find where is main function?
IDA-View-Open Subviews-Functions but, there are no functions.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GSpSI.png)
how can i set breakpoint with IDA? Thank you.